# Error when using django-admin-multiupload and django-imagekit together

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

At the moment I'm on my way using the django-imagekit to show thumbnails in an image-heavy view of a gallery app. For this purpose I'm using the 'model-method', means I'm creating the thumbnails within the model.

Now with the comfort of the admin in mind (upload multiple picture at once) I also want to implement a multi-upload form in the admin-view. To ease things a little bit I tried to use an app I found on GitHub, django-admin-multiupload (I'm not able to link to it because of my low reputations but that's the exact name for it on GitHub).
When I only use django-imagekit, everything works fine and I get nice thumbnails, just like expected. When I only use django-admin-multiupload, everything works fine and I'm able to upload multiple images just like expected.

The problem starts when I'm using both apps at the same time. The multiupload works still fine but when I'm opening the view, and actually implementing the thumbnail (only using both and not implementing the thumbnail works fine), where the thumbnails should be shown I will get the following error:

*OSError at /gallery/ - decoder jpeg not available*

You can see the full error here: http://pastebin.com/gtVYEeG7
My confusion starts when starting only the single app and it works. So as far as my knowledge goes, all PIL issues could not be present.
To provide some more information: I'm using a virtualENV with the following list of packages:

- pip
- django
- PIL
- pilkit
- django-imagekit
- django-amdin-multiupload

To also provide some of my implementet code, here it is:

**File: models.py**

```
class Image(models.Model):
"""the model for the images"""
# the foreign key from the event
event = models.ForeignKey('Event', related_name='images',
                            blank=True, null=True)
# the image itself
# file = models.FileField('File', upload_to='gallery/images/')
file = models.ImageField('File', upload_to='gallery/images/')

image_thumbnail = ImageSpecField(source='file',
                                processors=[
                                    ResizeToFill(300, 250)
                                ],
                                format='JPEG',
                                options={'quality': 40})

# image title to represent it in the admin interface
image_name = models.CharField(max_length=35, default='img')
# publication date of the image
pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published',
                auto_now_add=True)

# for a better representation of the image
def __str__(self):
    return self.image_name
```

**File: admin.py**

*(this one is mostly as suggested in the example from the django-admin-multiupload repo, can be viewed here: https://github.com/gkuhn1/django-admin-multiupload/blob/master/example/gallery/admin.py)*

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

from gallery.models import Event, Image

from multiupload.admin import MultiUploadAdmin
# Register your models here.

# allows inline add of single images
class ImageInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Image

# used to define the process_uploaded_file function
# so it will not be duplicated in the Admin-Classes
class GalleryMultiuploadMixing(object):
    def process_uploaded_file(self, uploaded, event, request):
        image = event.images.create(file=uploaded)
        return {
            'url': image.file.url,
            'thumbnail': image.file.url,
            'id': image.id,
            'name': image.image_name
        }

# admin class for event model
class EventAdmin(GalleryMultiuploadMixing, MultiUploadAdmin):
    inlines = [ImageInlineAdmin,]
    multiupload_form = True
    multiupload_list = False

    def delete_file(self, pk, request):
        obj = get_object_or_404(Image, pk=pk)
        return obj.delete()
admin.site.register(Event, EventAdmin)

# admin class for image model
class ImageAdmin(GalleryMultiuploadMixing, MultiUploadAdmin):
    multiupload_form = False
    multiupload_list = True

admin.site.register(Image, ImageAdmin)
```

**File: index.html**

```
<td><img class="img-responsive" src="{{ image.image_thumbnail.url }}" /></td>
```

If there is any need for additional information please don't hesitate to ask.
Thank you in advance and I appreciate any help.

**Edit**: Today I tried another way and recognized that the error is only appearing to images that were uploaded with the django-admin-multiupload and not if only images are shown that were uploaded with the normal method. Maybe this could help to find a solution.

Comment: In addition the link to the django-admin-multiupload repo on GitHub: [django-admin-multiupload](https://github.com/gkuhn1/django-admin-multiupload)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was mainly caused by a broken database that could be fixed by going back to an older version and reimplementing the new code. So there is no problem in django-admin-multiupload or django-imagekit.